# why can I not use label in custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am using a custom CollectionViewCell and when I want to add text to the custom cell I am struggling to do so. In the tutorial I am following it just says cell.label.text, but I don't seem to be able to do this here.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell

    // Configure the cell
    cell.label.text = "Sec \(indexPath.section)/Item  \(indexPath.item)"   /////error here: CustomCollectionViewCell does not have the member label.
    return cell 
}
```

The custom CollectionViewCell is defined as follows:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
}

override init(frame: CGRect){
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}


func setup(){
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0

}
}
```

Comment: Have you created any Label in your custom cell ?

Comment: yes, class is set to CustomCollectionViewCell. I updated the override

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create `IBOutlet` of `UILable` in your custom cell than you can access those `lable`  like `cell.label`  in your `cellForItemAt` method

```
class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
     @IBOutlet weak var lable: UILabel! //write this line and connect lable in storyboard.
}
```

**UPDATE:**
[image]

Open Storyboard -> Select your custom cell -> Right panel -> identity inspector -> class name -> write your class name here.

Comment: You need to add CustomCollectionViewCell class to in your storyboard than you can add  IBOutlet in you class.

Answer (score 1):

Assign your CustomCollectionViewCell class to the cell in the storyboard option then you can create a outlet for your label

```
class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
     @IBOutlet weak var lable: UILabel!
}
```